# Linear independence of $1, x, x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear dependence of the real valued functions $y_1 = 1, y_2 = x$ and $y_3 = x^2$  over the field of real numbers. Wronskian determinant shows that $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are linearly dependent for all $x$, but I can find non zero constant , that is the roots of equation $a\cdot y_1 + b\cdot y_2 + c\cdot y_3 = 0$,$ (a = 1/4 ,b = 1, c = 1)$.
How can we still call them independent?
Do we need to prove non zero constants $a,b,c$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for that to be a true linear dependence relation, it would have to apply for **all** x. That's one choice of constants, simultaneously true everywhere. Your choice applies only for $x=-\frac12$.